# How to update a progressbar that is instantiated within a RecyclerView's ViewHolder, from a different class?

Tags: java, android

I have a viewholder where I instantiate a progressbar that is attached to each row:

```
class SubmissionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, ISubmissions {
        @Bind(R.id.download_progress_bar)
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        @Override
        public void updateProgress(String s) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(s));
            if(Integer.valueOf(s)>=99){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
}
```

Here's the `ISubmissions` interface that is implemented by `SubmissionViewHolder`

```
public interface ISubmissions {

    void updateProgress(String s);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, to update the progressbar from a different class like so:

```
public class DownloadStream {

public DownloadStream() {
    ISubmissions submissions =  new Submissions$SubmissionViewHolder$$ViewBinder();
}
```

I'm unable to instantiate the `submissions` variable in the Class `DownloadStream`. What am I doing wrong?

Note: `SubmissionViewHolder` is an inner class of a class that extends the RecyclerView adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making interface, use `findViewHolderForItemId` on your `RecyclerView`. It will return `ViewHolder`.

All you need is cast it to your custom `ViewHolder` and use your `updateProgress()` method.

Another interesting functions for `RecyclerView` are:

- `findViewHolderForAdapterPosition`
- `findViewHolderForItemId`
- `findViewHolderForLayoutPosition`
- `getChildAt`
- `getChildViewHolder`

[RecyclerView documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)